# Designing of a PID Controller

Tags: control, control-system, pid-controller

First of all, I am new to this Q/A site. If I am doing anything wrong, please forgive me. I am having some trouble solving this problem:
Given the system of Figure(1), design a PID controller so that the system can operate with a peak time that is third(3 times) that of the uncompensated system at 20% overshoot and with zero steady-state error for a step input.

[image: Figure(1):Uncompensated feedback control system]

What I have done so Far:
At first:
[image]

Then finding \$ Z_{c} \$:
[image]

Now I have to find PD compensated System using this matlab code:

```
clear all
close all
clc
Gs=zpk([-8 -0.85],[-3 -6 -10],1)
rlocus(Gs)
```

But the result is frustrating as I am not getting any kind of result here:
[image]

Am I missing something here?? What's wrong with my solution up to the point. I have solved it with for 2/3 times and 1/3 times. Both times I was successful but in case of 3 times not getting any result.

Comment: I don't see where you got the \$G = 1.806\$.

Comment: It's actually sigma. And I got by calculating = -5.42*1/3=1.806

Comment: First, the root locus has a point on the real line if that point is to the left of an odd number of poles - zeros.  So when poles and zeros alternate, your root locus will be entirely on the real line.  That's a good sign that you've got a calculation wrong.

Comment: You're scaling your \$t_p\$ **down** by a factor of three; shouldn't you be scaling *both parts* of your dominant pole frequency **up** by a factor of three?

Comment: \$\sigma\$, \$G\$, eh, what's the difference?

Comment: Yes factoring by 3 both part gives me pretty much same 1/3 *(-5.42+10.6j)=1.806+3.53j;

Comment: That's the prolem here I don't identify the wrong calculation.

Comment: The system drawn on top has one zero and three poles. Take a look at your last root locus plot. There are two zeros and three poles. With Gs=zpk([-8 -0.85],[-3 -6 -10],1) you have added a second zero point. I dont see what 0.85 is supposed to be. Don't you have to calculate K?